# Rename a file called $MFT

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, filenames

I recovered a different system's $MFT file to my desktop for data recovery analysis, but the software named it "$MFT" - a reserved system name. Windows refuses to show it in a directory listing (even if I use `\\?\` or `\\.\` to prefix the path) so I can't rename it or delete it.

The file does exist on my desktop; I can see it in data forensics programs.

How can I rename the file from the CLI or some other way?

Comment: You can't copy the MFT between disks. If you want to, then rename it before.

Comment: @Moab It's not the *local* system's MFT, but another system's, for analysis. But I see that you've already noticed that with the dup link...

Comment: @harrymc - the question is not how to copy, but how to rename.

Comment: Use a Linux live USB?